# Store android sign certificate in version control

Tags: android, git, version-control, certificate

I've been playing for a while with android. Now that I have my application and been able to generate my signed release (testing purposes) I came with the question that I bring to you: **Should I save this certificate in my repo?**

Usually I prefer not to include any sensitive information in them, but when I was about to commit changes, I see that AndroidStudio modified `build.graddle` with **storeFile** and **storePassword** in it (I stored my certificate at `/home/user` as wasn't expecting any of this)

I'll love to hear your thoughts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what i do is.. i separate the app gradle into 3 part.

`build.gradle`        --> main gradle

import this 3 gradle into build.gradle
`dependencies.gradle` --> for list of dependencies
`signing.gradle`      --> for app signing keystore
`function.gradle`     --> for method call

in `signing.gradle` only contains like this

```
def alias = project.findProperty('APP_KEY_ALIAS') ?: EHALAL_KEY_ALIAS
def key_password = project.findProperty('APP_KEY_PASSWORD') ?: EHALAL_KEY_PASSWORD
def store_password = project.findProperty('APP_STORE_PASSWORD') ?: EHALAL_STORE_PASSWORD
def store_file = project.findProperty('APP_KEY_STORE_FILE') ?: EHALAL_KEY_STORE_FILE

if (alias && key_password && store_password && file(store_file).exists()) {
    android {
        signingConfigs {
            release {
                keyAlias alias
                keyPassword key_password
                storeFile file(store_file)
                storePassword store_password
            }
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                signingConfig signingConfigs.release
            }
        }
    }
}
```

with this, i can exclude only the signing gradle part in .gitignore, not the whole build.gradle part.

im suggesting you that you need to move all sensitive key into `gradle.properties` because its only in your local. refer [here](http://www.rainbowbreeze.it/environmental-variables-api-key-and-secret-buildconfig-and-android-studio/)

Comment: This is solid gold! +1. I need to understand graddle better but understood your approach perfectly. Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

You’d better not add the certificate in version control.

You can use **.gitignore** to ignore the file (`build.graddle`) if they are in git repository directory since the certificate is sensitive data.

And if you committed the file in version control before, you should remove the file from verson control by `git rm build.graddle --cached`.